# disable session default set id and name in yii

Tags: php, session, yii

I am setting the following session values in yii when the user logged in

the settings in my config file

```
'session' => array (
                'sessionName' => 'ems',
                'class' => 'CDbHttpSession'
        ),
```

in authenticate of user identity i've set these values

```
Yii::app()->session['logged_in'] = 1;
Yii::app()->session['display_name'] = $this->username;
```

but when i print the session i am getting these values

```
Array ([display_name] => admin@xxxxxxxxx [logged_in] => 1 
[8f9f85051824e063ad61f50fedc52f93__id] => admin@xxxxxxxxxx 
[8f9f85051824e063ad61f50fedc52f93__name] => admin@xxxxxxxxx 
[8f9f85051824e063ad61f50fedc52f93__states] => Array ( ) )
```

How to disable 8f9f85051824e063ad61f50fedc52f93__id,name or where they will be set

Comment: you also have `display_name` and `logged_in` in array,why dont you use them

Comment: i just want to know where and when these values will be set

Answer (score 0):

this values set in [CWebUser](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser) class, in login method, look [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L715) and [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L227).

"8f9f85051824e063ad61f50fedc52f93" is prefix generated in method [getStateKeyPrefix](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L542)